# Library for fitting parametric curves

Tags: optimization, curve-fitting, parametric-equations

Does anyone know of a library (any language, though preferably python/R/matlab) for parametric curve fitting, i.e. if you have a set of points in the plane {(x_i,y_i)} you can find parameter estimates for two (polynomial) functions y=f_y(t) and x=f_x(t) for some (arc-length?) parametrization t? This is especially useful if you have some multi-valued function (e.g. a circle) for which regression wouldn't work.

There are a number of papers detailing algorithms (e.g. 'Parametric Curve Fitting', Grossman 1971) but I can't find any corresponding software that would save a lot of time coding up.

Comment: Asking for library recommendations is usually considered as "off topic" on stackoverflow. This question is likely to be closed soon.

Comment: Is there a suitable forum stack exchange or otherwise on which to ask this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224904/where-can-i-ask-what-library-can-i-use-to-do-x

Comment: It's more that after half a day of googling, I couldn't find such a thing _anywhere_, so it hopefully wouldn't lead to anything opinion based other than it does/not exist. But I take your point

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, I ended up using the [princurve library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/princurve/index.html) in R based on [principal curves](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Principal_Curves.pdf) by Trevor Hastie.